# Was dual symmetric form especially significant to the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, sith, rogue-one, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels

In *Rogue One*, we saw Vader's castle on Mustafar. It was a Sith shrine of two high towers, symmetrical to each other.

[image]

In *Star Wars Rebels season 2 episode 21*, *"Twilight of the Apprentice"*, Ezra and his team located a Sith temple on Malachor and found their way on the top of it. There he discovered a two-part obelisk which followed the same design.

[image]

In *The Clone Wars season 6 episode 13*, *"Sacrifice"*, a Sith temple on Moraband was visited by Master Yoda. In this architecture, there was less space between the two masses, but the principle was the same.

[image]

After some brief browsing in Wookieepedia I also found a Legends example. The following image of a Sith temple is from the cover of a *Star Wars: Edge of the Empire* roleplaying game supplement, *"[Enter the Unknown](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Enter_the_Unknown)"*, by Fantasy Flight Games. Again, the same basic form.

[image]

These could be coincidences, but out-of-universe, it is also possible that there were be some kind of guidelines for the artists regarding to the Sith architecture and objects. Is there any information about this?

---

There was, however, one contradiction: Temple of the Whills on Jedha also represented the same style of architecture.

[image]

So, this formation may be related to the Force itself, however for some reason, none of the Jedi temples applied it. And obviously, the Sith seemed to favor it for some significance. Does anyone know about the background of this?

Answer (score 4):

Disney with new canon unfortunately erased much of earlier Sith history, and they are constantly pushing for Sith duality (Rule of Two, Sith Master and Apprentice). Best example for that would be aforementioned episode of Rebels S2E21 "Twilight of the Apprentice". As you could see, Maul cannot do anything alone, he needs Ezra to operate various machinery and artifacts in Sith temple on Malachor. Even elevators in that temple require two and no more people in order to work .All of this implies that Sith built that temple in the era where Rule of Two already exists, which contradicts earlier stories now part of Legends (for example in KotOR 2 game  ) . Therefore, Sith architecture most likely symbolizes their most important dictum - [Rule of Two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two)